# In Webpack 2, how do you add the date (or any other variable) to the banner output?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

In Webpack 2, there is a useful banner plugin allowing for chunks of text to be inserted into your entries. However, how does one enter dynamic variables into the banner?

I have tried

```
new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: `
/* 
 * Copyright © ACME Software, Inc - All Rights Reserved
 * Unauthorized copying of this file, via any medium is strictly prohibited
 * Proprietary and confidential
 * Written by Chris <cjke@acme.com.au>, ${new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString}
 */
      `,
      entryOnly: true,
      raw: true,
    }),
```

However the output looks like:

```
/* 
 * Copyright © ACME Software, Inc - All Rights Reserved
 * Unauthorized copying of this file, via any medium is strictly prohibited
 * Proprietary and confidential
 * Written by Chris <cjke@acme.com.au>, function toLocaleDateString() { [native code] }
 */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't invoke `toLocaleDateString` so that expression evaluated to the function as opposed to the result obtained by invoking it.

Invoking the method will provide you with the correct output:

```
${ new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString() }
//Invoke it by adding parenthesis here ---^
```